# confusion over `this` keyword

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I'm reading crockford's Javascript: The Good Parts and am messing around with this piece of code from the lesson invocation patterns:

```
var br = "<br />";

var add = function(a,b) {
    a + b;
}

var myObject = {
    value: 0,
    increment: function(inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === "number" ? inc : 1;
    }
};

myObject.increment(2);
document.write(myObject.value + br);    // 2

myObject.increment();
document.write(myObject.value + br);    // 3

myObject.increment(3);
document.write(myObject.value + br);    // 5

myObject.double = function() {
    var that = this;

    var helper = function() {
        that.value = add(that.value,that.value);
            return that.value;
    };

    helper();
};

myObject.double();
document.write(myObject.value);     //undefined
```

After the `double` method is called, I'm getting `undefined`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of the issue, but using reserved words as identifiers in JavaScript is not recommended.  `double` is a reserved word.

Comment: @Jacob: 50% correct: The plan to allow specific data types in Javascript no longer exists and double is therefore no longer on the reserved word list in the latest standards. Since many people still use earlier browsers where this was defined as a reserved word you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your "add()" function is missing a `return` statement:

```
var add = function(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

A function without a `return` statement actually ["returns" undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Comment: Sorry dude - these questions are always so exciting

Comment: @Cem I don't understand why others didn't also upvote yours. We're not judges in a "Who answered first" competition. +1 for you! :)

Comment: I tried to compensate the point difference by adding an explanation.

Comment: @j0k: its not generally the one submitted first, if I didnt wrote that I got beaten no one would know. Its generally the top most answer who gets the up votes. BTW, I dont post if I see the same answer but I didnt even see new answer posted text before I sent it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should return the result in the add function:

```
var add = function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
```